# How to fix postfix on macOS Sierra 10.12.6?

Tags: osx, postfix

I can't seem to get postfix to work. Every time I send something and error comes up `(TLS is required, but our TLS engine is unavailable)`

### **Trouble Shooting Steps** (that didn't work)

- Deleted `openssl` in `/opt/local/bin` forcing it to use the one in `/usr/bin`
- Replaced `openssl` in `/opt/local/bin` with `openssl` in `/usr/bin` from macOS High Sierra
- Replaced `openssl` in `/usr/bin` with `openssl` in `/usr/bin` from macOS High Sierra
- Installed `openssl` from `brew`

### /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

### /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 XXXXXXXX@gmail.com:XXXXXXXX
```

Can't Upgrade to High Sierra so please HELP!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

10.12.6 has a bug that is causing this to occur, even though the [Security Patch that apple released](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208221) was for 10.13.1 and 10.12.6. Upgrading to High Sierra with 10.13.1 will ultimately fix your issue without any configuration changes.

Comment: Is there any chance you can tell me what files change so I can copy them over from a high Sierra install. I have already tried copying openssl

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to upgrade to High Sierra.

If it's not possible for some reason, you can work around this bug by using `stunnel` and relay mail from postfix unencrypted via local encrypted tunnel according to [this guide](https://raimue.blog/2018/03/22/postfix-with-relayhost-over-stunnel-on-macos-10-12-sierra/) (all credits go to Rainer Müller):

1. Install [MacPorts](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html)
2. `$ sudo port install stunnel certsync`
3. Create `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.example.mail.plist` and put the following into it:

```
<!-- /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.example.mail.plist -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.example.mail</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/opt/local/bin/stunnel3</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>-r</string>
        <string>smtp.gmail.com:587</string>
        <string>-n</string>
        <string>smtp</string>
        <string>-v</string>
        <string>2</string>
        <string>-A</string>
        <string>/opt/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem</string>
    </array>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>nobody</string>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Listeners</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SockNodeName</key>
            <string>localhost</string>
            <key>SockServiceName</key>
            <string>555</string>
            <key>SockType</key>
            <string>stream</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Wait</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

4. Configure launchd to run stunnel3:
   `$ sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.example.mail.plist`
5. Test the connection:
   `nc localhost 555`
6. Edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to made postfix use local tunnel instead of directly connecting to an SMTP server:

```
relayhost = [localhost]:555
smtp_tls_security_level = may
```

(encryption level should be lowered as well)

7. In `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` change `smtp.gmail.com:587` to `localhost:555`
8. Reload postmap:

```
sudo postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Now your mail should work like a charm!

P.S. Use this command to see mail logs in runtime for debugging:

```
log stream --predicate  '(process == "smtpd") || (process == "smtp")' --debug
```

P.P.S. I have XCode 9.2 installed. It may be necessary for installing/runing stunnel3.